# Why is the dismiss button on this bootstrap alert not working in my flask app?

Tags: html, flask, web, bootstrap-5

I have jquery, the boostrap css link in the head, and the bootstrap javascript before the closing body tag. Also I am using Flask.

```
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>Success!</strong> {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Here are the jquery and boostrap css, inside of the head tag

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and finally the bootstrap javascript before the closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I got the bootstrap alert from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing). You can see how it is supposed to look. On my webpage it looks like this:

[Bootstrap alert on my wbepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obbf7.png)

The button on my webpage has no functionality whatsoever.

What could be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

Incase anybody has the same issue all I had to do was replace

```
class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
```

With

```
class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"
```

On the button.